# Create layout of images without assigning them static layoutparams in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have layout in which I have 7 imageviews which is one item of listview. I want to create this view without giving any static height and width. I want to create it in such a way that it should work for any resolution. the images are loading from server.

following is the view

[image]

following is the cide I am using.but I dont want to assign static height and width like 65dp and all.. plzz help me

```
  <ImageView 
       android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"

            android:id="@+id/mainimg"
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="137dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="144dp"

            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" />



                <ImageView android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" />



                <ImageView android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img3"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img4"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img5"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img6"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better to use layout_weight to achieve this ...

Comment: ankita the width and height of first imageeview is fix..,means you want that in that size?

Comment: height is fix but not width..

Comment: for what al views should I assign weigth.. @BlackTiger

Comment: first thing change your linearlayout to relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...may be it helps you.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_image_bg_big"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Replace the `android:background` with your `@drawable`.

Comment: I am using src to assign image as images are coming from server

Comment: Load the image bitmap from the url and then set is as the `imageView.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap)`.

Comment: So..where is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="144dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainimg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```